# How to get JSON response using ruby

Tags: ruby, json, api, http, response

I am trying to get a JSON response through API using http.
here is my code snipet

```
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
      http.open_timeout = 300
      http.read_timeout = 300
      if uri.scheme == 'https'
        http.use_ssl = true
        http.verify_mode = ::OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
      end
http.request(Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri, initheader = {'header' => 'headervalue'})).body
```

But am getting response like

```
[{\"Id\":\"986\",\"DataContentType\":2,\"DataContent\":\"content type\",\"lang\":\"ENGLISH\",\"Name\":\"Name\"}]
```

Comment: This is the json response.

Comment: That looks like a valid JSON string. To parse it, use `JSON.parse(...)`

Comment: Then please "close" the question (write an answer and accept - and be nice to @Stefan).

Answer (score 0):

This response is looks like JSON you only need to parse that JSON using `JSON.parse(string_here)`

Thanks.